# How can I check the given pattern into an input dialog?

Tags: java, groovy

I have an input dialog and I want to check if user typed a specific pattern. For example, user can type any number `-` and any number. Something like this `10-20`. How can I check if user typed this kind of pattern?

Comment: May be regex, something like `input.matches("\\d+-\\d+")` ?

Comment: Simos, are the numbers guaranteed to be positive integers?

Comment: @hfontanez yes, should be only positive integers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the numbers are guaranteed to be positive integers, @Eritrean's suggestion is correct.

```
String input = "10-20";
String regex = "\\d+-\\d+";
System.out.println("Input is valid? " + input.matches(regex));
```

For the current input, it will print out that the input is valid ("true") because it matched the given regular expression. An input like `10-A0` would not be valid and thus, will print out "false".

If the input is not guaranteed to be a positive integer, these are my suggestions accordingly:

1. For signed values, add `[-+]?` in front of each digit pattern: `[-+]?\\d+-\\d+[-+]?`. This will match signed integers by allowing optional sign characters in front of the number.
2. For floating-point numbers, I suggest `\\d*\\.?\\d+`. This regular expression expects the numeric value to have optional digits before the decimal point, and an unbounded number of digits after. It also matches integer values as well. So, a regular expression like `\\d*\\.?\\d+-\\d*\\.?\\d+`, should be able to account for integers and floating-point numbers separated by a dash. If you require signed floating point numbers, follow suggestion in #1 above.

Comment: @SimosSigma you bet! Thank you for responding to my answer so quickly. That's rare nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the input is correct do this:

in Java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+-[0-9]+",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("10-20");
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
if(matchFound) {
  System.out.println("Match found");
} else {
  System.out.println("Match not found");
}
```

Comment: "_I don't know what language you are working_" The tags on the question should've been a giveaway.

Comment: `String` class contains a `matcher` method.